# How secure are Meteor client side DB requests?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, client

Let's imagine 3 machines:

- Client
- Meteor server
- MongoDB server

If i perform a mongodb request from the client, it will connect to Meteor, or directly with mongodb? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In client Meteor, meteor runs MiniMongo, a js API implementation of mongoDB.

As written in [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#client-collections)

> On the client, there is no direct connection to the MongoDB database,
>   and in fact a synchronous API to it is not possible (nor probably what
>   you want). Instead, on the client, a collection is a client side cache
>   of the database. This is achieved thanks to the Minimongo library—an
>   in-memory, all JS, implementation of the MongoDB API.

For write requests- the client saves data which is reflected in MiniMongo which then communicates to the Meteor Server. Based on allow/deny rules the data may be written to the MongoDB Server or denied. (Assuming, `insecure` package is removed)

In short, Client(MiniMOngo) and Meteor Server communicates through DDP, Meteor Server and MongoDB communicates through NodeJS MongoDB Driver. All communications from client goes to  server and according to the rules defined may/maynot be written in the MongoDB DB.

How Secure is the Meteor Client side DB request?
The answer to this is '*It Depends*'. According to Meteor [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny), it is not recommended to rely on allow/deny rules for security. It is always preferred to do this through methods as discussed [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/)

Some Resources :
[Allow/Deny Rules in Meteor](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny)
[Collections in Meteor](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html)
[Read about MiniMongo Here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/minimongo)